# How can I get the function name from the map file generated by Doxygen?

Tags: linux, doxygen

I am using Doxygen on linux to analyze my project code. After running doxygen, I want to save relations of functions into my database. I opened the map files generated by doxygen, and I get the content like below.

```
<map id="G" name="G"><area shape="rect" id="node3" href="xxxx" title="xxxx" alt="" coords="xx,xx,xx,xx"/>
```

Why the name and id are both "G"? How can I get the right function name?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? When not using the newest version of doxygen (1.8.15) can you try this version to see what happens? Can you give a small, doxygen compileable,  example where you see this occur?

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.7.6 and I cannot update it to the newest version because of some company rules. I have tried the 1.8 version on my windows, and it worked perfectly.  I am afraid I cannot give examples since the project is top-classified. But i figured out another way to get the function names through dot files generated by doxygen anyway.

Comment: Well good to hear that you could use the 1.8.?? version on windows and it worked there. Pity that you cannot use an newer version of doxygen, the 1.7.6 version is from december 2011 and the problem has been solved in version 1.8.1.2 of July 12, 2012. By staying on 1.7.6 you are missing out on a lot of improvements. Regarding the example, an artificial example should always be possible (but not relevant anymore now as you have seen that the problem is not present in the newest versions of doxygen).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the "digraph G" is used in the version 1.7.6 (December 2011) for all graphs. With version 1.8.1.2 (July 12, 20112) this has been changed in the name of a title.